# what is the purpose of trainable parameters in batch normalization?

Tags: conv-neural-network

If the purpose of Batch Norm is to normalize inputs to the next layers, what is the purpose of introducing learnable/trainable parameters (Gamma and Beta)?

Answer (score 3):

I may have found the answer here - https://kratzert.github.io/2016/02/12/understanding-the-gradient-flow-through-the-batch-normalization-layer.html